# How to change working copy withOUT affecting HEAD

Tags: git

I am in the middle of a complicated merge and need to change my working copy.  `--theirs` won't work for [details].

```
git checkout <tree-ish>
```

changes the HEAD pointer.  I just want to change my working copy; eg `git-diff` would show the differences between whatever i set my working copy to, and what HEAD currently is.  I really do mean just change the contents of the working copy to some [in the context of this question] arbitrary other commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout <tree-ish> -- .
```

Comment: thanks, blanked on using a path not a glob for that :)